# Get subview from AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following `AlertDialog` and its `onClick` method:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alertDialog.setView(View.inflate(this, R.layout.barcode_alert, null));

alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Search", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(@NotNull DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // how to get editTextField.getText().toString(); ??
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});
```

The XML I inflate in the dialog (`barcode_alert.xml`) contains, among other things, an `EditText` field, and I need to get its string value after the user taps the Search button.
My question is, how do I get a reference to that field so I can get its text string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
final View v = View.inflate(this, R.layout.barcode_alert, null); //here
alertDialog.setView(v);

alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Search", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(@NotNull DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        ((EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.edit_text)).getText().toString(); //and here
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});
```

Comment: That's it! I was missing that I needed to pull the `EditText` from the view.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
final View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(this, R.layout.barcode_alert, null);
final EditText editTextField = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
editTextField.setOnClickListener(MyActivity.this);
alertDialog.setView(v);

alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Search", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(@NotNull DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    String enteredValue = editTextField.getText().toString(); // get the text from edit text
    dialog.dismiss();
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can inflate your view and get a reference to a variable:

```
View v = View.inflate(this, R.layout.barcode_alert, null);
```

you can use `findViewById` to get a reference to your view. Make sure that your variable is final or a member variable. Otherwise you cannot access it in the onClickListener

```
final EditText editText = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.your_edit_text
```